# Video output suddenly dropping

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, games

I have an Nvidia card and am currently using the latest 460 drivers. Ubuntu 20.04 and kernel 5.4.

Recently when I'm in the middle of a game suddenly the video output just stops. I can steal hear the audio running and I can tell that the game is still running based on the audio and using the keyboard and mouse. But the monitor acts as if it's not plugged in.

I ran this:

```
#!/bin/bash
_now=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")
_file="gpu_pwr_log_$_now.txt"

while true; do
        (date; gpustat -FP; echo '-----------') | cat >> "/var/log/temp/$_file"
        sleep 5;
done
```

while I started a game thinking it's either a temperature or power issue. However the temp and power remain fairly low but suddenly gpustat doesn't output anything at all anymore. I assume that roughly the same moment when the monitor becomes "unplugged".

I've tried the same with nvidia-smi but it just shows the same values until I do a hard reboot.

How can I debug this problem?

This is the output I get from the script above:

```
Sa 17. Apr 21:40:15 CEST 2021
pcname                   Sat Apr 17 21:40:15 2021  450.102.04
[0] GeForce GTX 1080 Ti | 61'C,  34 %,  42 %,  175 / 280 W |  4983 / 
11164 MB | user(8M) user(8M) user(8M) user(8M) user(8M)     
user(8M) user(2808M) root(485M) user(181M) user(54M)     
user(2M) user(1390M) user(8M) user(8M) user(8M) user(8M) 
user(8M) user(8M) user(2808M)
-----------
Sa 17. Apr 21:40:20 CEST 2021
pcname                   Sat Apr 17 21:40:20 2021  450.102.04
[0] GeForce GTX 1080 Ti | 61'C,  34 %,  45 %,  160 / 280 W |  5047 /     
11164 MB | user(8M) user(8M) user(8M) user(8M) user(8M) 
user(8M) user(2872M) root(485M) user(181M) user(54M) user(2M) 
user(1390M) user(8M) user(8M) user(8M) user(8M) user(8M) user(8M)     
user(2872M)
-----------
Sa 17. Apr 21:40:25 CEST 2021
-----------
Sa 17. Apr 21:40:30 CEST 2021
-----------
Sa 17. Apr 21:40:36 CEST 2021
-----------
Sa 17. Apr 21:40:41 CEST 2021
-----------
Sa 17. Apr 21:40:46 CEST 2021
```

gpustat just suddenly stops getting any output because the driver is suddenly gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was a defective Power source. Swapped that out with a new one and everything is working again.